# terminal: open editor by click on stacktrace line

Tags: python, terminal, editor

I want python stacktrace lines to act like hyperlinks in a terminal. My favorite editor should open the file and go to the correct line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo_eins_dt/djangotools/utils/smtputils.py", line 73, in _inner_to_outbox
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo_eins_dt/foo_mail/tests/EditTest.py", line 289, in test_something
    beleg_ids=importutils.import_msg_file(temp)
TypeError: bar() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Up to now I use gnome-terminal, but I could switch to a different terminal.

Example: I want to click on `File "/home/foo_eins_dt/foo_mail/tests/EditTest.py"` and the file EditTest.py should be opened at line 289.

Comment: I think you need to modify the source. Maybe this helps: http://blahonga.yanson.org/2009/09/modifying-gnome-terminal-to-understand.html

Answer (score 3):

For the internet future: This is possible in OS X in [iTerm 2](https://iterm2.com/index.html)

Here is my setup with Sublime Text: `~/bin/magic-iterm-open.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from subprocess import call

if len(sys.argv) > 2:

    pathToSubl = "/Users/rainer/bin/"

    filename, linenum = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    rest = "" if len(sys.argv) < 4 else sys.argv[3]

    if not filename.endswith('.py'):
        # I believe this approximates iTerm's default
        call(['/usr/bin/open', filename])
    else:
        newLinenum = linenum
        if not str.isdigit(linenum):
            line = linenum.split(",")
            if len(line) > 1:
                newLinenum = filter(str.isdigit, line[1])

        command = ["{0}subl".format(pathToSubl),
                   "--add",  # If you'd like to add to your current sublime project
                   "{0}:{1}".format(filename, newLinenum)]

        call(command)
```

And the config in iTerm2:

[image]

All credit goes to an old redit post, here: https://www.reddit.com/r/SublimeText/comments/1kanze/iterm2_jump_to_location_in_sublime_text_23/

Comment: Thank you very much. I like your term "internet future". Yes, I think usability for the human to computer interface is still open to many improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any terminal supports this functionality out of the box. My terminal (iTerm on Mac) opens the file when I do Cmd-Click on file name. But it ignores the line number.

On the other, investigate IDEs with Python support and embedded terminal. It's more likely some of them support your use case.

Comment: I know that an IDE has features like this. In this case, I would like a link from a terminal.